# Expand the List of Class Members in VS 2008

Tags: c#

Is there any add-in for VS2008 Pro that provides me the ability to expand and see the list of members of each class - methods, properties,etc... - by expanding its tree node in Solution Explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not possible from solution explorer, but is available via the Class View. go to the View menu and click on Class View to open it up.

Answer (score 2):

Object Browser?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exy1facf%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In Solution Explorer you can click either on the project or individual file and select 'View Class Diagram'.  It creates a diagram for all your classes.  To see members of the class click on the down arrow next to the class name.

Comment: should the project be able to compile before I can do this? cuz I do it and I get the error" no types were found in the selection"